# Chemical difference between dexedrine and methamphetamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, pharmacology

I am a newbie at chemistry and wondering what the key difference between [dexedrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextroamphetamine) and [methamphetamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methamphetamine) HCL is. I know that [methamphetamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methamphetamine) has an extra methyl group compared to [Adderall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adderall). But what about [dexedrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextroamphetamine)?

Comment: Read [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adderall) article.

Comment: I have read these articles....I want an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 4):

### Adderall

Adderall is a drug(trade name) that contains a combination of four salts of amphetamine (equal parts racemic amphetamine and dextroamphetamine, which produces a (3:1) ratio between dextroamphetamine and levoamphetamine, the two enantiomers of amphetamine).

Racemic amphetamine: levoamphetamine and dextroamphetamine respectively. Notice [the dash-wedge notation](https://sciencenotes.org/wedge-and-dash-notation-for-3d-chemical-structures/). The methyl group is pointing away from the reader in the former structure and is pointing towards the reader in the latter structure.

[image]

Enantiomeric amphetamine: chiral molecules that have a mirror orientation of one another. See [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/enantiomer-of-amphetamine).

[image]

### Dexedrine

Dexedrine is the trade name for dextroamphetamine

### Methamphetamine

It is a drug similar in structure but has an extra methyl group (So, primary amine becomes secondary amine).

[image]

Also, do note that [a simple change in the drug structure can change the potency.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139502/why-is-heroin-a-more-potent-drug-than-morphine-despite-having-a-similar-structu?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -1):

The difference is that it is not the same molecule (group $ \ce {NH_2} $ for one, group $ \ce {NH-CH_3} $ for the other) so not the same properties.

[image: amphetamine]
[image: metamphetamine]

Comment: The N-Methyl is important because it changes the metabolism profile

Comment: @Waylander: So would you say that methamphetamine and adderall are more similar to each other compared to Dexedrine and Methamphetamine?

Comment: No - Adderall contains the 2 enantiomers of ampthetamine, dexedrine is a single isomer. Neither contain methampthetamine.

Comment: @Waylander: But methamphetamine and adderall feel.subjectively similar.

Comment: A general principal in medicinal chemistry - a small change can make a huge difference